# PatternSyntaxException: Illegal Repetition when using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I don't know much regex, but I need to match a simple pattern. The following should return true,

```
Pattern.matches("{\"user_id\" : [0-9]*}", inputLine)
```

when inputLine is

```
{"user_id" : 34}
```

However, I'm getting this exception:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{"user_id" : 24}
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Unknown Source)
    at org.whispercomm.manes.server.http.IntegrationTest.createUser(IntegrationTest.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

The `{` and `}` are special in Java's regex dialect (and most other dialects for that matter): they are the opening and closing tokens for the repetition quantifier `{n,m}` where `n` and `m` are integers. Hence the error message: "Illegal repetition".

You should escape them: `"\\{\"user_id\" : [0-9]*\\}"`.

And since you seem to be trying to parse JSON, I suggest you have a look at [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Comment: As a side note, brackets `[` `]` are also reserved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442162/java-replace-all-square-brackets-in-a-string

Comment: Same for parenthesis ( )  used in capture groups.

Answer (score 7):

There should be plus operator:

```
user_id : [0-9]+
```

Double apostrophes only when the string has to contain it.

When the string including curly brackets use:

```
\{user_id : [0-9]+\}
```

Comment: The answer is I needed to escape the `{}`. However, I did need a `+` instead of a `*`

Answer (score 0):

**@IntelliJ** IDE for example detects the inconsistency. Depending on the input, What you could do is to escape the characters or handle the problem using the data provided by the exception.

[image]

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;

public class StackOverflow {
    private static String REGEX = "{\"user_id\" : [0-9]*}";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);

            // get a matcher object
            String input = "Hello stackoverflow";
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
            input = matcher.replaceAll("something");
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException e){
            System.out.println("PatternSyntaxException: ");
            System.out.println("Description: "+ e.getDescription());
            System.out.println("Index: "+ e.getIndex());
            System.out.println("Message: "+ e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Pattern: "+ e.getPattern());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
PatternSyntaxException: 
Description: Illegal repetition
Index: 1
Message: Illegal repetition near index 1
{"user_id" : [0-9]*}
 ^
Pattern: {"user_id" : [0-9]*}
```

**Possible solution**

```java
catch... ex
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
    sb.insert(ex.getIndex() + 1, "\\");
    matcher.replaceAll(sb.toString())
```