# Eclipse is saying there's an Illegal repetition in this regex

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

```
if(possTape.matches("{\\(\\d+,\"[^:=;@\"\\)\\(\\{\\}\\[\\]]+\"\\)(,\\(\\d+,\"[^:=;@\"\\)\\(\\{\\}\\[\\]]+\"\\))+}"))
```

But what does that mean? I've tested this regex on regexpal (with adjustments made so it works as Java) but I don't see where there is an illegal repetition?

Comment: I *think* you missed escaping one of the last parenthesis. (By the way, that was a joke considering the amount of escaping in case anyone was going to correct me)

Comment: And it appears to match `{(number,"quoted text"),(number,"quoted text")}` (if the first and last {} get escaped) with restrictions on what can be in the quoted text (no :, =, ;, @, ", ), (, {, }, [ or ]).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

escape the curly brackets?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751482/patternsyntaxexception-illegal-repetition-when-using-regex-in-java):

The { and } are special in Java's regex dialect (and most other dialects for that matter): they are the opening and closing tokens for the repetition quantifier {n,m} where n and m are integers. Hence the error message: "Illegal repetition".

Comment: Heh! I was staring a the `+`s, trying to work out what was wrong. Didn't even see the `{}`!

Comment: Legend! Didn't realise the outside ones needed to be included but that makes total sense now, thank you!