# RegEx for finding empty catch in PHP source code

Tags: regex, eclipse

I have a huge legacy PHP code base with a lot of code like this:

```
try {
  doSomethingImportant();
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

There is a whole lot of code where someone thought it was a good idea to swallow all exceptions and then do nothing with them.  Sometimes there are comments:

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // do nothing
}
```

I am hoping to plug some RegEx into Eclipse's search and find the bulk of these places so I can investigate and refactor.  It's easy enough for me to find the catch blocks:

```
catch.*\{.*\}
```

What is an appropriate way to match when a catch block has one or more of the following conditions:

- Whitespace Only
- `//` comments and whitespace only
- `/* */` comments and whitspace only
- `//` and `/* */` comments and whitespace only

`//` is easy but I'm not sure how to handle multi-line stuff with `/*` `*/` and what not.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure who made the comment "At 71k one should know not to put a technology (PHP) in the title and instead use it as a tag", but it is perfectly appropriate to mention a technology in a title to set the context.  I didn't label it there... it's not standalone... it's part of the title itself.  I also didn't add PHP as a tag because in the end, it's not what the question is about.  I mentioned it in the title to add some context, that's all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
catch[^{]*\{\s*(?:\/\/[^\n]*|\/\*(?:[^\n]*\n)*[^\n]*\*\/)*\s*}
```

You can use this to match multilines.

See demo

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/122

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a regex that matches only **empty** catch blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  That works for finding everything within the catch block, but I also need a way to exclude regular code.  That is, if it isn't a comment and isn't whitespace, I don't want to match.  I want to ignore places where there is actual code for handling the exceptions, and only want to find places where there is no code for handling exceptions.  Does that make sense?

Comment: That's awesome!  RegEx wizard.  Thank you very much!  That covers most of my cases... there is still the multi-line comment case though.  `/* something \n something on the next line */`.

Comment: @vks Perfect!  I'm going to read through the regex101 explanation and try to figure out how it works now.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: @vks Yeah, I'm waiting for Stack Overflow to let me.  And now I'm trying to figure out what I need to escape to get it working in Eclipse.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525870/eclipse-is-saying-theres-an-illegal-repetition-in-this-regex  "Illegal repetition near index 9" it tells me.  So, I think I just need to escape some brackets.

Comment: @vks Figured it out:  `catch[^{]*\{\s*(?:\/\/[^\n]*|\/\*(?:[^\n]*\n)*[^\n]*\*\/)*\s*}`   That works beautifully.  188 matches...  now I'm going to go bang my head for a few weeks while I figure out what the original intent of this try/catch code was.  :-)

Comment: @Brad yups in java you need to escape `{}`