# java regex: replace ${var}

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to replace a String like:

```
Hello, my name is ${name}. I am ${age} years old.
```

with

```
Hello, my name is Johannes. I am 22 years old.
```

Variables are stored in  a HashMap.
My code so far:

```
private void replace() {
        HashMap<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<String, String>();
        replacements.put("name", "Johannes");
        replacements.put("age", "22");

        String text = "Hello, my name is {name}. I am {age} years old.";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(.+?)\\}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String replacement = replacements.get(matcher.group(1));
            builder.append(text.substring(i, matcher.start()));
            if (replacement == null) {
                builder.append("");
            } else {
                builder.append(replacement);
                i = matcher.end();
            }
        }
        builder.append(text.substring(i, text.length()));
        System.out.println(builder);
    }
```

It's wokring fine, but I would like to replace ${var} and not {var}.
Changing it to Pattern.compile("\${(.+?)\}"); will throw an PatternSyntaxException: "Illeagal repetition".

Escaping the $ (Pattern.compile("\\${(.+?)\}") will cause an compiling error.

So **How to I have to change my Pattern to accept ${var} instead of {var}**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The { character is reserved in most regex libraries for repetition along the lines of `{n,m}`. Try the regex

```
\\$\\{(.+?)\\}
```

Comment: Not in most flavors, in such cases anyway. (Only) Java is picky about it, most others don't care. Only when it could be interpreted as a range operator does it *need* to be escaped.

Comment: Hi, Konstantin, can you check my related thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075425/java-regex-pattern-to-find-unix-env-vars-formatted-as-either-var-or-var.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In your replacement examples you forgot to also escape the leading { as well as the $.

So you need to do:

```
Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(.+?)\\}");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping the curly brackets to avoid that illegal repetition error.

As stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751482/patternsyntaxexception-illegal-repetition-when-using-regex-in-java):  The { and } are special in Java's regex dialect (and most other dialects for that matter): they are the opening and closing tokens for the repetition quantifier {n,m} where n and m are integers. Hence the error message: "Illegal repetition".