# Java RegEx pattern to find Unix env vars formatted as either $VAR or ${VAR}

Tags: java, regex

This works for ${VAR}:

```
Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(.+?)\\}");
```

But I am struggling to format it so that it also accepts $VAR to the next word boundry (\b).  Because the text can be

```
$FIRSTVAR.${SECONDVAR}LITERAL
```

and then I want to detect both $FIRSTVAR and ${SECONDVAR} and if the first is "X" and the second if "Y", I want to replace it to **X.YLITERAL**.  The template uses both  $VAR and ${VAR} styles, prefers the former if the var is followed with a non-word character but uses the latter if it is (just like in the example I gave above).

I tried

```
Pattern.compile("\\$(\\{|)(.+?)(\\}|\b})");
```

But that matches **FIRSTVAR.${SECONDVAR** as group(2).  So it's not good.
Thanks in advance

Comment: related thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526291/java-regex-replace-var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write:

```
Pattern.compile("\\$(?:(\\w+)|\\{(\\w+)\\})")
```

Naturally, this means that *either* `matcher.group(1)` *or* `matcher.group(2)` will be the variable-name — the other will be `null` — so you'll have to check both.

Another, less-robust option is to write:

```
Pattern.compile("\\$\\{?(\\w+))\\}?")
```

but then it would replace e.g. `$SECONDVAR}` with `Y` rather than with `Y}`.

---

**Edited to add:** If you're using Java 7, I think you should be able to write

```
Pattern.compile("\\$(?:(?<varname>\\w+)|\\{(?<varname>\\w+)\\})")
```

and then retrieve the variable-name using `matcher.group("varname")`. (I haven't tested that in Java, because I only have Java 6 handy, and Java 6 doesn't support named capture-groups. But it *does* work in Perl.) See ["Group name" in the `java.util.regex.Pattern` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#groupname) and [the javadoc for `java.util.regex.Matcher.group(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: does \w incluce underscores?  my vars have underscores

Comment: I have been burned in the past by using \w because of its limitations.  That's why I don't like using it

Comment: @foampile Yes, it has underscores, \w is like [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Comment: @foampile: `\w` includes ASCII letters, digits, and underscores. I think it's exactly what you need; all regular Bash variables have names matching `\w+`. (By the way, it doesn't make sense to avoid `\w` but still use `\b`, since the latter is defined in terms of the former.)

Comment: The `(?:group)` tells that the group will not be backreferenced. So it acts as a normal group but you won't be able to use matcher.group(1) to retrieve it.

Comment: @ruakh, it works, the only thing i don't like is having to determine if it's group 1 or 2.  i will wait a little to see if anyone submits a cleaner solution before accepting your answer.  thanks a lot

Comment: @foampile: I've added another possibility in my answer. I wouldn't consider it "cleaner", but it does remove the need to check both groups, so you might prefer it.

Comment: actually, the first solution is OK, i can resolve it with a ternary in one line.  thanks, it works

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a new pattern

```
Pattern.compile("\\$(\\{?(\\w+)\\}?)\\.?");
```

It would backreference you something like: [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uL0wY4) But that would match something like `$firstvar$secondvar}literal` and I dont know if its correct.

And if its only for 2 variables...

```
Pattern.compile("\\$(\\{?(\\w+)\\}?)\\.(?:\\$(\\{?(\\w+)\\}?))?");
```

[Demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/wX9gH9)

A third review if it's what you want [Demo 3](http://regex101.com/r/nX1aN5)

And remember you can name groups with `(?<groupname>group)`