# Java replace all square brackets in a string

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to remove square brackets from a string, but I don't know how.

```
String str = "[Chrissman-@1]";
str = replaceAll("\\[\\]", "");

String[] temp = str.split("-@");
System.out.println("Nickname: " + temp[0] + " | Power: " + temp[1]);
```

But my result is: [Chrissman | 1]
The square brackets doesn't get removed.

I tried using a different regex: `"\\[.*?\\]"`, `"\\[\\d+\\]"`
but the result is the same, the square brackets still attached on the string.

Edit:

I tried:

```
str.replaceAll("]", "");
str.replaceAll("[", "");
```

And now I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 0
[
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 168, accepted):

The replaceAll method is attempting to match the String literal `[]` which does not exist within the `String` try replacing these items separately.

```
String str = "[Chrissman-@1]";
str = str.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","");
```

Comment: Yikes I'm about to be skeeted.  (I mean this as a compliment)

Comment: Nope, it's not working.

Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 0
[
^
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)

Comment: Square brackets absolutely *are* "special" characters in regular expressions - they're used for ranges, e.g. `[a-z]`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for pointing this out.  I was searching Java special character lists, but I forgot replaceAll was looking for regex.

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian I removed the unescaped brackets portion of the answer, I apologize for any confusion.  Is the original throwing an error?

Comment: Now it's working :-) Thank you very much @KevinBowersox.
I must review my knowledge in Java regex. I totally forget it.

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian: But why would you want to use a regular expression at all?

Comment: As a side nte curly brackets `{` `}`are also reserved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751482/patternsyntaxexception-illegal-repetition-when-using-regex-in-java

Answer (score 82):

Your regex matches (and removes) only subsequent square brackets. Use this instead:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");
```

If you only want to replace bracket pairs with content in between, you could use this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\[(.*?)\\]", "$1");
```

Comment: This should be the accepted Answer, cleaner and more concise

Answer (score 29):

You're currently trying to remove the *exact* string `[]` - two square brackets with nothing between them. Instead, you want to remove all `[` and separately remove all `]`.

Personally I would avoid using `replaceAll` here as it introduces more confusion due to the regex part - I'd use:

```
String replaced = original.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

Only use the methods which take regular expressions if you *really* want to do full pattern matching. When you just want to replace all occurrences of a fixed string, `replace` is simpler to read and understand.

(There are alternative approaches which use the regular expression form and really match patterns, but I think the above code is significantly simpler.)

Answer (score 11):

use regex `[\\[\\]]` -

```
String str = "[Chrissman-@1]";
String[] temp = str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split("-@");
System.out.println("Nickname: " + temp[0] + " | Power: " + temp[1]);
```

output -

```
Nickname: Chrissman | Power: 1
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You may also do it like this:

```
String data = "[yourdata]";
String regex = "\\[|\\]";
data  = data .replaceAll(regex, "");
System.out.println(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this regex to replace every string inside brackets:

```
var= var.replaceAll("\\[\\w+", "[*").replaceAll("\\]", "]");
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
   Use this line:) String result = strCurBal.replaceAll("[(" what ever u need to remove ")]", "");

    String strCurBal = "(+)3428";
    Log.e("Agilanbu before omit ", strCurBal);
    String result = strCurBal.replaceAll("[()]", ""); // () removing special characters from string
    Log.e("Agilanbu after omit ", result);
   
    o/p :
    Agilanbu before omit : (+)3428
    Agilanbu after omit :  +3428

    String finalVal = result.replaceAll("[+]", ""); // + removing special characters from string
    Log.e("Agilanbu finalVal  ", finalVal);
    o/p
    Agilanbu finalVal : 3428
            
    String finalVal1 = result.replaceAll("[+]", "-"); // insert | append | replace the special characters from string
    Log.e("Agilanbu finalVal  ", finalVal1);
    o/p
    Agilanbu finalVal : -3428  // replacing the + symbol to -
```

Comment: after removing braces i want to add - at start how to achive this  ex: -123

Comment: String finalVal1 = result.replaceAll("[()]", "-");  // pls use this code, this is wat u asking?      
 o/p
    Agilanbu finalVal : -3428  /* replacing the () symbol to -  */

Comment: my value is (324) , i want it as -324, using this  m.replaceAll("[()]", "-"); iam getting -324-, please help me out

Comment: String result = "(3428)";
        Log.e("Agilanbu finalVal 0  ", result);
        String finalVal11 = result.replaceAll("[(]", "-");
        Log.e("Agilanbu finalVal 1 ", finalVal11);

        String finalVal = finalVal11.replaceAll("[)]", ""); 
        Log.e("Agilanbu finalVal 2 ", finalVal);

Answer (score 0):

```
String str, str1;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter a String : ");
str = sc.nextLine();


str1 = str.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]", "");



System.out.print(str1);
```