# replaceAll - Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this output `[4,-3],[-3,-1],[2,-4],[-4,1]`
and this is the code that gives me this output:

```
public static String[] arg() throws IOException {
    String prova =getString().replaceAll(" 0","] [");
    String prova1=prova.replaceFirst("0","[");
    String prova2=prova1.replaceAll("%0","]");
    String prova3=prova2.replaceAll(" ",",");
    String prova4=prova3.replaceAll("],["," ");
    System.out.println(prova4);
    String[] strArray = getString().split(" ");

    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
    return strArray;

}
```

My problem is that I would have as output this [4,-3] [-3,-1] [2,-4] [-4,1] that is, a blank space in place of this `],[`. I think that `String prova4=prova3.replaceAll("],["," ");` should do this, but it produce several error.

This is the error: `Unclosed character class near index 2
],[`

Comment: First argument to replaceAll is a regular expression. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: `replaceAll` uses regular expressions, so you'd have to escape your brackets using `\\[` and `\\]`. Duplicate/similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442162/java-replace-all-square-brackets-in-a-string

Comment: There's no need to escape `]`. It has no special meaning, outside of a character class.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `replaceAll()` expects a regex pattern, not a string literal. `[` and `]` have special meanings in regex patterns, they group character classes. You can fix your problem by escaping the `[` and `]`:

```
String prova4 = prova3.replaceAll("\\],\\[", " ");
```

To get the output you want though, you need to only replace the comma, not the brackets:

```
String prova4 = prova3.replaceAll("\\],\\[", "\\] \\[");
```

Comment: Great String prova4 = prova3.replaceAll("\\],\\[", "\\] \\["); is the solution. But do u think that my code is "beautiful"? Or is there the possibility to do it better?

Comment: It's a very small piece of code to judge the beauty of. I think it's perfectly acceptable code.

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
String prova4=prova3.replaceAll(","," ");
```

Comment: Hi with your advice i have this: [4,-3 -3,-1 2,-4 -4,1]

Comment: @nonac See my answer for the fix.

Answer (score 1):

From [Doc](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

There are 12 characters with special meanings: the backslash `\`, the caret `^`, the dollar sign `$`, the period or dot `.`, the vertical bar or pipe symbol `|`, the question mark `?`, the asterisk or star `*`, the plus sign `+`, the opening parenthesis `(`, the closing parenthesis `)`, and the opening square bracket `[`, the opening curly brace `{`, These special characters are often called `"metacharacters".`

If you want to use any of these characters as a literal in a regex, you need to escape them with a backslash.

Therefore what you need to try with : `\\]`

Comment: The character you are suggesting escaping, closing square bracket, is not among the ones with special meanings that you listed (but opening square bracket is).

Answer (score 1):

You solution doesn't work because the first argument to the `replaceAll` is a regular expression. The characters `[` and `]` have a special meaning, as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
Character classes
[abc]           a, b, or c (simple class)
[^abc]          Any character except a, b, or c (negation)
[a-zA-Z]        a through z or A through Z, inclusive (range)
[a-d[m-p]]      a through d, or m through p: [a-dm-p] (union)
[a-z&&[def]]    d, e, or f (intersection)
[a-z&&[^bc]]    a through z, except for b and c: [ad-z] (subtraction)
[a-z&&[^m-p]]   a through z, and not m through p: [a-lq-z](subtraction)
```

You have to escape them so the code looks like this `replaceAll("\\],\\[", "] [")`. However I don't think that in your case that you need to use `replaceAll`, as you may use [replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29), which will yield cleaner code `replace("],[", "] [")`.