# How to replace all characters in a String without using replace() methods , StringBuilder, or StringBuffer, or Arrays?

Tags: java, string

I have an assignment that requires me to replace all character 'e' with the character '%'. I'm not allowed to use any other classes like StringBuilder, StringBuffer, and I can't use Arrays or replace() methods.

This is my code:

```
public String replace(String s, char letter)
{
    String myString = "";
    String myWords = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){

        if (s.charAt(i) != ' ' && s.charAt(i) != letter) {
            
            myString = myString + s.charAt(i);

        } else {

            if (s.charAt(i) == letter){
                myWords += '%';
            }
            myWords += myString + " ";
            myString = "";
        
        }
        

    }
    return myWords;

    
}
```

This is my code so far, but it's not giving me the correct output.

```
Input: Always eating apples
My Output: always %ating %
Correct Output: always %ating appl%s
```

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay The title says without using `replace`

Comment: `String.join("%", s.split("" + letter))`

Comment: Please do not delete your code.  Your question was of reasonable quality when you included your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: [Java replace all square brackets in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442162/java-replace-all-square-brackets-in-a-string) does not appear to answer this question because the solutions there use the `replace` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are complicating using myWords

```
public static String replace(String s, char letter)
{
    String myString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){

        if (s.charAt(i) != letter) {
            myString = myString + s.charAt(i);
        } else {
            if (s.charAt(i) == letter){
                myString = myString + '%';
            }
        
        }
        

    }
    return myString;

    
}
```