# Regular Expression to extract string from JSON response

Tags: json, regex

I am trying to extract the value from timeZoneId but [regexr](http://regexr.com/3cm1i) says no match.

here is the JSON code:

```
{
  "dstOffset": 0,
  "rawOffset": 25200,
  "status": "OK",
  "timeZoneId": "Asia/Jakarta",
  "timeZoneName": "Western Indonesia Time"
}
```

and when I test on regexplanet its says **`Illegal repetition {\s*"timeZoneId"\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*\}`**

Can anyone help and explain what i'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

I am parsing the result in a while loop, so I only need the RegEx for the line when it match this  `"timeZoneId": "Asia/Jakarta",` I want to grab out the `Asia/Jakarta`.

Thanks

G

Comment: ... If it's JSON, why wouldn't you use a JSON parser??

Comment: You are requiring `{}` around the timeZoneId in your expression, which it doesn't have.

Comment: I am escaping the {} on regexr as \{\s*"timeZoneId"\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*\} and still no match.

Comment: @torazaburo I did put it in and I put an example to show regexp said no match.

Answer (score 0):

The { and } brackets are special characters in regex and need to be escaped. See more here: [PatternSyntaxException: Illegal Repetition when using regex in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751482/patternsyntaxexception-illegal-repetition-when-using-regex-in-java)

Also, as dustmouse said, you are requiring {} around the timeZoneId but there isn't just whitespace between the { and the "timeZoneId". All your other fields are there which is causing it not to match.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot more than just whitespace between the opening brace and "timeZoneId".

You want:  `/^\s*"timeZoneId"\s*:\s*(.+?)(?=$|,)/m`

But, use a JSON parser. For example [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)

```
echo '{
    "dstOffset": 0,
    "rawOffset": 25200,
    "status": "OK",
    "timeZoneId": "Asia/Jakarta",
    "timeZoneName": "Western Indonesia Time"
}' | jq -r '.timeZoneId'
```

```
Asia/Jakarta
```