# String replacing nested JSON in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have a Scala method that will be given a String like so:

```
"blah blah sediejdri \"foos\": {\"fizz\": \"buzz\"}, odedrfj49 blah"
```

And I need to strip the "foos JSON" out of it using pure Java/Scala (no external libs). That is, find the substring matching the pattern:

```
\"foos\" : {ANYTHING},
```

...and strip it out, so that the input string is now:

```
"blah blah sediejdri  odedrfj49 blah"
```

The token to search for will *always* be `\"foos\"`, but the content inside the JSON curly braces will always be different. My best attempt is:

```
// Ex:  "blah \"foos\": { flim flam }, blah blah"  ==>  "blah  blah blah", etc.
def stripFoosJson(var : toClean : String) : String = {
    val regex = ".*\"foos\" {.*},.*"
    toClean.replaceAll(regex, "")
}
```

However I my regex is clearly not correct. Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?

Comment: It is not easy to specify `ANYTHING` with a regex because it can contain nested objects that have braces also... I'd go with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752225/how-do-i-find-the-position-of-matching-parentheses-or-braces-in-a-given-piece-of), by finding matching braces and taking substring.

Comment: Thanks @insan-e (+1) - you're right, however in my particular case I *know* I will nost have any nested JSON inside the curly braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 solutions I came up with, hope it helps. I think you forgot to handle possible spaces with `\s*` etc.

```
object JsonStrip extends App {

    // SOLUTION 1, hard way, handles nested braces also:
    def findClosingParen(text: String, openPos: Int): Int = {
        var closePos = openPos
        var parensCounter = 1 // if (parensCounter == 0) it's a match!
        while (parensCounter > 0 && closePos < text.length - 1) {
            closePos += 1
            val c = text(closePos)
            if (c == '{') {
                parensCounter += 1
            } else if (c == '}') {
                parensCounter -= 1
            }
        }
        if (parensCounter == 0) closePos else openPos
    }

    val str = "blah blah sediejdri \"foos\": {\"fizz\": \"buzz\"}, odedrfj49 blah"
    val indexOfFoos = str.indexOf("\"foos\"")
    val indexOfFooOpenBrace = str.indexOf('{', indexOfFoos)
    val indexOfFooCloseBrace = findClosingParen(str, indexOfFooOpenBrace)
    // here you would handle if the brace IS found etc...
    val stripped = str.substring(0, indexOfFoos) + str.substring(indexOfFooCloseBrace + 2)
    println("WITH BRACE COUNT: " + stripped)

    // SOLUTION 2, with regex:
    val reg = "\"foos\"\\s*:\\s*\\{(.*)\\}\\s*,\\s*"
    println("WITH REGEX: " + str.replaceAll(reg, ""))
}
```

Comment: Thanks enormously @insan-e (+1) - Solution #2 worked just perfect for me!

Answer (score 2):

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/5efJqf/1) `\\"foos\\": {(.*?)}` should match what you want, in most regex engine, you might need to replace `"` with `\"`. If your JSON can contains other curly brackets, you can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/5efJqf/2) `\\"foos\\": \{(?>[^()]|(?R))*\}`, it uses recursion to match balanced groups of brackets. Note that this one only works in pcre regex engine, others won't support recursion.

Comment: Thanks @Croutonix (+1) - no, I won't have nested JSON inside the curly braces. However, I had to change your regex to `\"foos\": {(.*?)}` because the double backslashes were causing Scala compiler errors. Also, your first regex is giving me a `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 7 "foos": {(.*?)}` exception...any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8751574/5288316). You have to add a backslash to curly braces. `\"foos\": \{(.*?)\}`

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure you are making these regexes safe for Scala? When I change my regex to `"\"foos\": \{(.*?)\}"`, I get `scalac` compiler errors stating `invalid escape character`... thanks again though! (and +1)