# Java; String replaceAll giving error

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace `"{` from below `String`:

```
public static void main(String args[]){  
    String input="Subtitle,\"{\"key\": \"IsReprint\", \"value\":\"COPY\"}";

    input=input.replaceAll("\"{", "{"));        

    System.out.println("String ::::"+input);
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1
    \"{
     ^
```

Comment: Do you mean to use `replace` instead?

Comment: you cannot use `"\"{"` it is wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PatternSyntaxException: Illegal Repetition when using regex in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751482/patternsyntaxexception-illegal-repetition-when-using-regex-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

The first you have to escape the `{` with `\\{`, because replaceAll use regex so you have to escape the `"` and `{`:

```
input=input.replaceAll("\"\\{", "{");
```

The second is to use `replace` instead if you don't have this complicated regex :

```
input=input.replace("\"{", "{");
```

Answer (score 0):

[`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) takes a regex as an argument. `{` has a special meaning in regex, so have to escape `{` by doing

```
input=input.replaceAll("\"\\{", "{");
```

or use [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)), which doesn't take a regex as an argument.

```
input=input.replace("\"{", "{");
```

Comment: `{ has a special meaning in regex` If not ambiguous it does, otherwise it doesn't. Java could still be the hold out on this, but every other engine disambiguates.

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping the "{" character correctly when you are calling replaceAll.

You need to use "two slashes" \\ before any regular expression (regExp).

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String input="Subtitle,\"{\"key\": \"IsReprint\", \"value\":\"COPY\"}";

    System.out.println(input.replaceAll("\\{", "*"));
}
```

**My example** replaces the "{" character with a *:

```
"\\{", "*"
```

**Running**, you get the ouput:

```
Subtitle,"*"key": "IsReprint", "value":"COPY"}
```

---

**With the input:**

```
String input="{{ }}";
```

**You get the output:**

```
** }}
```

Comment: Thanks Guys...It worked.I used as below. input=(input.replaceAll("\"\\{", "{"));